# Complex linq statement - nested groups/where/sum/select

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object such as the sample below

```
object = {
        [0] {Name: "Foo", Customer: "Alex", Number: "33.2", Amt: 100.50, FileId: 12345611, FileNumber: "0987-123"}
        [1] {Name: "Bar", Customer: "Josh" Number: "1", Amt: 100.50, FileId: 456546456, FileNumber: "0987-123"}
        [2] {Name: "Foo", Customer: "Alex", Number: "33.2", Amt: 110.00, FileId: 12345611, FileNumber: "0987-123"}
        [3] {Name: "Foo", Customer: "Frank", Number: "9.8", Amt: 100.50, FileId: 324234, FileNumber: "9999-123"}
        [4] {Name: "Test2", Customer: "Bob" , Number: "1.9", Amt: 100.50, FileId: 782724, FileNumber: "0987-123"}
        [5] {Name: "Foo", Customer: "Alex" , Number: "33.2", Amt: 50.80, FileId: 9872561, FileNumber: "8181-1273"}
    }
```

I need it to look like the below

```
groupedObject = {
        [0] {Name: "Foo", 
                Rows: {
                        row: {
                            [0] {Number: "33.2", Customer: "Alex", Details: {
                                        [0] {Amt: 210.50, Number: "33.2", FileId: 12345611, FileNumber: "0987-123"}
                                        [0] {Amt: 50.80, Number: "33.2", FileId: 9872561, FileNumber: "8181-1273"}
                                    }
                                }
                            [1] {Number: "9.8", Customer: "Frank", Details: {
                                        [0] {Amt: 100.50, Number: "9.8", FileId: 324234, FileNumber: "9999-123"}
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
            }
        [1] {Name: "Bar", 
                Rows: {
                        row: {
                            [0] {Number: "33.2", Customer: "Josh", Details: {
                                        [0] {Amt: 100.50, Number: "1", FileId: 456546456, FileNumber: "0987-123"}
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
            }
        [2] {Name: "Test2", 
                Rows: {
                        row: {
                            [0] {Number: "1.9", Customer: "Bob", Details: {
                                        [0] {Amt: 100.50, Number: "1.9", FileId: 782724, FileNumber: "0987-123"}
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to group by Name, which is then grouped by Customer within the name, and then the customer details within that customer, and details with the same fileID need the rows combined. Is this possible with linq?

If it helps with visualization below is what I need, but in XML.

```
<main>
    <UniqueNames>
        <randominfo>true</randominfo>
        <randominfo2>false</randominfo2>
        <head>
            <Name>Foo</Name>
        </head>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <Number>"33.2"</Number>
                <Customer>"Alex"</Customer>
                <Details>
                    <Detail>
                        <Amt>210.50</Amt>
                        <Number>"33.2"</Number>
                        <FileId>12345611</FileId>
                        <FileNumber>"0987-123"</FileNumber>
                    </Detail>
                    <Detail>
                        <Amt>50.80</Amt>
                        <Number>"33.2"</Number>
                        <FileId>9872561</FileId>
                        <FileNumber>"8181-1273"</FileNumber>
                    </Detail>
                </Details>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </UniqueNames>
    <UniqueNames>
        <randominfo>true</randominfo>
        <randominfo2>false</randominfo2>
        <head>
            <Name>Bar</Name>
        </head>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <Number>"33.2"</Number>
                <Customer>"Josh"</Customer>
                <Details>
                    <Detail>
                        <Amt>100.50</Amt>
                        <Number>"1"</Number>
                        <FileId>456546456</FileId>
                        <FileNumber>"0987-123"</FileNumber>
                    </Detail>
                </Details>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </UniqueNames>
    <UniqueNames>
        <randominfo>true</randominfo>
        <randominfo2>false</randominfo2>
        <head>
            <Name>Test2</Name>
        </head>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <Number>"1.9"</Number>
                <Customer>"Bob"</Customer>
                <Details>
                    <Detail>
                        <Amt>100.50</Amt>
                        <Number>"1.9"</Number>
                        <FileId>782724</FileId>
                        <FileNumber>"0987-123"</FileNumber>
                    </Detail>
                </Details>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </UniqueNames>
</main>
```

I've tried the below...
Grouping my Object by the name, and then listing each object for each name..

```
var testgroup = TestObject.GroupBy( item => item.Name)
    .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key, Items = group.ToList() })
    .ToList()
```

Then I also have another one for getting all the details

```
var Details =
                (from c in TestObject
                    group c by new
                    {
                        c.Number,
                        c.FileId,
                        c.FileNumber,
                    } into cFIDs
                    select new FileAllocation()
                    {

                        FileAmount = cFIDs.Sum(s => s.Amt),
                        Number = cFIDs.Key.Number,
                        FileId = cFIDs.Key.FileId,
                        FileNumber = cFIDs.Key.FileNumber,
                    }).ToList();
```

The above allowed me to group and generate the details I needed, and the first one has the group by name and the listed rows for each... I also tried the below.

I'm just not sure how to put it all together

Comment: GroupBy will be your friend in this case

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site is not supposed to be a coding service but a site where you can get help when you've tried something yourself but it's not working. Please provide us with code of your attempt and information about how and why that is not working for you.

Comment: `Is this possible with linq?` it is indeed. As mentioned already, `What have you tried so far`, we'll be glad to help when we know what you have tried and where you are having issues.

Comment: Just updated my question with a few things I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 separate `GroupBy` statements and then a projection of each to the right properties for your output. There's a few ways to achieve but probably the easiest to read goes like this:

```
var result = inputs.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(g => new {
            Name = g.Key,
            Rows = g.GroupBy(x => new {x.Customer, x.Number})
                .Select(g2 => new{
                    Number = g2.Key.Number,
                    Customer = g2.Key.Customer,
                    Details = g2.GroupBy(x => new {x.FileId,x.FileNumber})
                                .Select(g3 => new {Amt = g3.Sum(x => x.Amt), g2.Key.Number, g3.Key.FileId, g3.Key.FileNumber})

                })
        });
```

Here's a live working example with your data: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ozcWUM

The above uses anonymous objects, you can easily project to your custom objects if you wished. eg the last projection could read:

```
...
.Select(g3 => new FileAllocation{Amt = g3.Sum(x => x.Amt), g2.Key.Number, g3.Key.FileId, g3.Key.FileNumber})
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a ton. It's not 'exactly' what I needed, but from what you gave me I am able to alter and see the capabilities of it and go from there! I've got it working the way I want now. Appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Interested what's not right because its exactly what you *described*

Comment: Correct, it is exactly as I described. Maybe I worded my comment wrong. It's exactly what I needed in terms of what I explained. Your explaination allowed me to add onto it with the ACTUAL data that I did not include in my original post, since I was not having issues with that portion. All is good! Thanks!